# Loop retrieving only one result in Laravel with Yajra Datatable

Tags: laravel, foreach, datatables, yajra-datatable

This is my query:

```
$albix = DB::table('albi')
  ->select(['albi.id'])
  ->join('albi_user', 'albi.id', '=', 'albi_user.albi_id')
  ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
  ->get();
```

This is my `foreach` loop that should retrieve multiple items:

```
foreach ($albix as $a) {
    return $albi->id == $a->id ? 'alert-warning' : '';
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: If you want to get the first result only replace your `get()` with `first()`

Comment: i want to retrieve multiple items but with this foreach i retrieve only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return stop your loop

`if($albi->id == $a->id){ return  'alert-warning';}`

```
$data = []
foreach ($albix as $a) {
   $data[$a->id] = $albi->id == $a->id ? 'alert-warning' : '';
}
return $data;
```

Comment: With an else condition it doesn't work! You know why?

Comment: because if statement not run else stop your loop
i can't see your full codes but
`
$data=[];
foreach ($albix as $a) {
   $data[$a->id]=$albi->id == $a->id ? 'alert-warning' : '';
}
return $data;

`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through database results, and if the `id` is the same, return the correct object:

```
$user = (object)['id' => '123'];
foreach ($db_results as $row) {
    if ($user->id == $row->id) {
        return $row;
    }
}
return []; // id not found, handle your fallback
```

In your case:

```
foreach ($albix as $a) {
    if ($albi->id == $a->id) {
        return $a;
    }
}
return []; // id not found, handle your fallback
```

Comment: Sorry I saw you wanna retrieve multiple items. Can you show an example of your desired outcome so I can code it for that way. If you just wanna get all items, why not `return $albix;`?